# How to filter posts with a wp query by a custom dropdown type field with the magic fields plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-query, custom-field, plugin-magic-fields

I have been trying to obtain posts by filtering by two custom fields in a wp query, the problem is that I do not get the expected result, which is that I filter by country and by a value that I am using in the dropdown that the magic plugin provides me fields which is for adding custom fields, when searching the database I cannot find the value that is assigned to the post which I suspect is a string, I cannot change the plugin since this is a somewhat old page and I would have to do an extensive migration

```
$query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'multimedia-sistemas',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => wp_is_mobile() ? '3' : '12',
            'offset' => '0',
            'paged' => '1',
            'meta_query' => array(
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'pais',
                    'value' => '1189',
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                 array(
                    'key' => 'pagina',
                    'value' => $page,
                    'compare' => '='
                 )
            )
            
        );

        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
```